# Creating image upload facility in php on one.com

Tags: php, file, upload

I am trying to create a simple file upload facility for my website using php, I believe most of the code is fine. I'm using one.com and I have an assets folder which then has an image folder inside this is where I want the images to be uploaded to. I am unsure of what to put for the file image path though.When I try and upload an image the 'Done' is echoed to the page but my image doesn't appear in the folder.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


// GETTING INFO FROM FILE WE'VE UPLOADED
$file = $_FILES['image'];
$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['image']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
//Splitting the filename on the extension
$fileExt= explode ('.', $fileName);
//Getting the extension from the file and tolower so we can find out if it is an allowed file type
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
//File types that we are going to allow
$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png');

if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
    if($fileError === 0){
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;

        $fileDestination = '/assets/images/'.$fileName;   //PROBLEM??

        move_uploaded_file($FileTmpName, $fileDestination);
        echo"Done?";
    }else{
        echo "There was an error?";
    }}
    else {
    echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
}}
```

Comment: try     $fileDestination = './assets/images/'.$fileName;

Comment: I would provide more detail about whether this is a syntax error or just a conceptual question about architecture. It is not clear whether you are asking use to fix a bug or solve something else.

Comment: The filepath should represent a public/private endpoint on your static server. If these images are specific to some context in your Model (User, Company, Product, Review, etc) then I would create some form of naming pattern so that the `filepath` can be re-generated from info from your model. For example, if I was saving images for a Review of a Cafe, the path I saved on my server might be `/images/review/:reviewId/:uuid.jpeg` where `:reviewId` is pull from the Review Model and :uuid is generated at time of upload, providing the ability to select photos by review where all are unique.

Comment: 1. there are existing methods in php to get file info and extension.

2. your extension match is case insensitive

3. your file path is possibly root fs-relative. have you checked your root for the dir? 

4. you're not testing for exceptions on the `move_uploaded_file` method. do a `try + catch` / `or die()` or evaluate the output of the method. 

5. how are you logging / debugging this script?

Answer (score 0):

Does PHP have permission to write to that directory?

You aren't checking for errors on move_uploaded_file(), you are just echoing "Done?".

Check the permissions on the images directory, then check the file has been moved.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($FileTmpName, $fileDestination)){
   //File was moved
}else{
  //Error
}
```

Also, try changing

```
 $fileDestination = '/assets/images/'.$fileName;   //PROBLEM??
```

to

```
$fileDestination = 'assets/images/'.$fileNameNew;   //PROBLEM??
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The path your using is wrong. You need either the full path or the path relative to the location of the file your running from. try either

```
$fileDestination = getcwd().'/assets/images/'.$fileName;
```

for the full path, or just

```
$fileDestination = './assets/images/'.$fileName;
```

for the path relative to the current directory. This assumes that the file your running is in the same directory that contains the assets folder.